# Folderstructure for template files

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a restriction for template folders?
Like for name or structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Drupal doesn't place restrictions on the names of any template file or folder.

Restrictions for file naming are handled at the OS level.

Comment: like collecting view-xyz.tpls in view folder ?

Comment: Do you mean naming or structure _conventions_, maybe, not restrictions?

Comment: i know the suggestions for hierachical naming tpl files,
i just didn't now if it is ok to move them inside the template-folder without limitation.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that's no problem at all. You can put your template files under the root, templates/ and templates/**, they should all be picked up

Answer (score 0):

No,there is no restriction for the file or folder naming structure. Drupal doesn't follow that name/structure restrictions.